# Detect post action in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to do something when a form is submitted.

```
var ispostaction = false;
$("#myform").submit(function () {
 ispostaction = true;
});
```

When the form is submitted the `.submit(function ())` is not called.
Is there anything wrong that I'm doing? I have the form id as myform.

I would appreciate any help.

Here's my xhtml page. I'm using JSF 2

```
<form id="myform" class="someclass" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
action="pagename.jsf" method="post">
// custom input text field
// selectOneMenu
// a few more input text fields 
// submit button is below
<input id="javax.faces.ViewState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="...." name="javax.faces.ViewState">
</form>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not called?  Can you put an alert in there to be sure?

Comment: Yeah I put an alert message and also put break points in firebug

Comment: My guess is a need to add it to the document ready

Comment: @mplungjan - good guess.  My guess is the case is incorrect:  MyForm != myform.

Comment: I added it to the document.ready function but still no use. Please check edit for xhtml page

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML - I do not see why you have the action on the submit button rather than on the form tag, but I do not do JSF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery documentation:

```
The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit
a form. It can only be attached to <form> elements. Forms can be submitted
either by clicking an explicit <input type="submit">, <input type="image">,
or <button type="submit">, or by pressing Enter when certain form elements
have focus.
```

Calling the submit function will not trigger the submit event. You can "fix" this by adding a hidden button which you click from jquery instead. Most, if not all, browsers unfortunately display the same behavior.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="myform" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
action="posturl" method="post">
// custom input text field
// selectOneMenu
// a few more input text fields 
// submit button is below
<input id="javax.faces.ViewState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="...." name="javax.faces.ViewState">
<input type="text" value="a value" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" style="display: none;" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").bind('submit', function() {
        alert('');
    });
    $("#submit").click();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```